# Castle Windsor with .net 3.5 framework

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, castle-windsor

How can I use Windsor in my .net 3.5 solution? Can I use the binaries built for .net 2.0? Do I need to compile the Castle Windsor source myself, targeting 3.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the .net 2.0 binaries in your 3.5 solution without any problem. They are both built for the same version of the CLR. There is no need to recompile the source code targeting 3.5

There's a nice [picture](http://www.flickr.com/photos/75251211@N00/313250406/) outlining different versions of the framework with the corresponding CLR version.